# Can I use the voltage divider formula and why?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, circuit-analysis

In `Problem 7.13` ([official solutions pdf](https://textbooks.elsevier.com/manualsprotectedtextbooks/9781558607354/manual/agarwal_and_lang-solutions.pdf)) of Agarwal and Lang's Foundations of Analog and Digital Electronic Circuits, the voltage at node \$v_A\$ is found using the voltage divider formula
$$v_A = {R_G \over R_L + R_F + R_G}V_S $$
due to the fact that the gate of a MOSFET has no input current. Since the MOSFET is in saturation, thus acting like a dependent current source, is it correct to use the voltage divider formula if the current in resistor \$R_L\$ is not the same current passing through \$R_F\$ and \$R_G\$?

[image]

Comment: Either they're doing it wrong, or something is missing from the explanation.  You are correct in that.  A way to solve this would be to find the transistor drain current (their \$i_D\$) as a function of the gate voltage (their \$v_A\$), then find the gate voltage as a function of the supply current and the drain current.  Then rearrange those equations until \$i_D\$ and \$v_A\$ are on the left side of each, and now you have two equations in two unknows, and they may even be solvable.  (They'll be quadratic; just remember you could have been a business major, and forge ahead).

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: If you work it out, post it as an answer -- such behavior is encouraged here.

Comment: Will do, thanks!